# how to play mp3 file in phonegap using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing one phoneGap application. And I used the below code for application but i got the error.

Below is my folder structure of phonegap

```
App
--.svn
--hooks
--platforms
--plugins
--www
-- --index.html
-- --Song
-- -- --Rang Laal.mp3
```

I am using below code for play the song:

```
<script>
    function playAudio(id) {

        var url = audioElement.getAttribute('src');
        var my_media = new Media('Song/Rang Laal.mp3',
                // success callback
                 function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); },
                // error callback
                 function (err) { console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err); }
        );
        // Play audio
        my_media.play();
    }
</script>
```

Below is the error that i am getting

```
Error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement       
          phonegap-1.4.1.js (line 671)
```

Actually my all .mp3 file will store in server. I have to just play from mobile. please suggest a way for that. using url we can able to play? or some plugin available in phonegap?

Awaiting for response.

Answer (score 1):

i tried this plugin      `cordova-plugin-media`
which worked perfectly. 
Check that [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/)